# For loop failing in mid-loop Error in grobs[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot line graphs of samples taken from wells, specifically for four "chemicals", and then, stack those 4 charts for each well and save to pdf. I haven't practiced in a bit, and I'm rusty. Currently, my for loop is stopping in the middle, and popping the above error.

Below is roughly what my data looks like AND the packages I'm calling:

```
   ID            date         chemical           result
   <chr>        <dttm>              <chr>        <num>
 1 MW-01        2020-01-06 10:30:00 chemical 1~  0.02
 9 MW-02       2020-01-06 13:34:00 chemical 2~   0.02

library(openxlsx)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(doBy)
library(lubridate)
library(officer)
library(readxl)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggridges)
library(cowplot)
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library("plyr")
library(dplyr)
```

Below is my for loop without the if statements for plots 3-4 (for brevity), which are verbatim the first/second plot with the other chemicals plugged in. Well list is a dataframe with two columns: well ID and a generated figure number. I am noticing that my script is running for about 20% of the wells and then erring out.

```
for(l in 1:n_wells){

  plot.dat<-data.frame(subset(tableH,(id %like% well_list[l,1])))

  stacked.dat<-subset(plot.dat,(chemical %like% c("chemical 1","chemical 2",
                                                       "chemical 3","chemical 4")))

  well<-well_list[l,1]

  #min.date<-as.POSIXct("2020-01-01")
  #max.date<-as.POSIXct("2020-07-01")

  chm1table_lp <- subset(stacked.dat,(chemical %like% "chemical 1"))
  chm2table_lp <- subset(stacked.dat,(chemical %like% "chemical 2"))
  chm3table_lp <- subset(stacked.dat,(chemical %like% "chemical 3"))
  chm4table_lp <- subset(stacked.dat,(chemical %like% "chemical 4"))

  if(nrow(chm1table_lp)>0){

    minc1 <- min(chm1table$result)
    maxc1 <- max(chm1table$result)

    chm1_plot <- ggplot(chm1table_lp, aes(x=sample_date,y=result))+
    geom_line(data=chm1table_lp,aes(x=sample_date,y=result,group=1),color="orange",size=1)+
      geom_point(data=chm1table_lp,shape=1,color="orange",size=2)+
      labs(y="mg/L",x="Date")+
      scale_color_discrete("Legend") +
      scale_x_datetime(date_labels="%m/%Y",limits=c(min.date,max.date))+
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(minc1,maxc1),
                         breaks= breaks_extended(n=10))+
      ggtitle(well)

    plot_list[[k]] <- chm1_plot

    k=k+1
  }

 if(nrow(chm2table_lp)>0){
    minc2 <- min(chm2table$result)
    maxc2 <- max(chm2table$result)
    print("in chm2 if statement, min and max work")

    chm2_plot <- ggplot(chm2table_lp, aes(x=sample_date,y=result,group=1))+
      geom_line(data=tdstable_lp, aes(x=sample_date,y=result),color="blue",size=1)+
      geom_point(data=chm2table_lp,shape=1,color="blue",size=2)+
      labs(y="mg/L",x="Date")+
      scale_color_discrete("Legend") +
      scale_x_datetime(date_labels="%m/%Y",limits=c(min.date,max.date))+
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(minc2,maxc2),
                         breaks= breaks_extended(n=10))+
      ggtitle(well)

    print("chm2 plot works")
    print(tds_plot)

    #adding to plot list
    plot_list[[k]] <- chm2_plot
    print("chm2 plot added to list")

    #increase index by 1
    k=k+1
    print("index increase after chm2")
  }
  multi_plot <- plot_grid(plotlist = plot_list,ncol=1,align = "v")

  pdfname<-paste(well,".pdf",collapse=NULL,sep="")

  ggsave(pdfname)

  plot_list <- vector(mode="list")

  k=1
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the loop is working for some of the wells, your problem obviously isn't a crude syntax error.  It's probably a feature of the data for a particular well (or wells).  So the first thing I'd want to do is see the data for the well that is erroring.  Put a `print` at the top of the loop to monitor progress.  Check the data for the well that's causing the problem.  Find out which plot is causing the error. If you can't figure it out, then `dput()` the data for that well and create a new simple, self-contained example for THAT dataset and THAT specific plot.

Comment: Thanks @Limey, I will give that a go, and report back!

Comment: @Limey, thanks again for your reply. I put in the print statement, and found that the loop is, apparently, failing when it reaches a well that does not have data for chemical 1. I was under the impression, however, that my IF statement would have taken care of that. Any ideas?